# Unable to encrypt data using AES encryption in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, encryption, aes, dio

I have downloaded a video file and now want to encrypt it using aes encryption but i am getting certain errors which are:

```
I/flutter (23630): Data downloding....
I/flutter (23630): Encrypting file...
E/flutter (23630): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Response<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<int>'
E/flutter (23630): #0      _encryptData (package:data_encryption/main.dart:154:42)
E/flutter (23630): #1      _downloadAndCreate (package:data_encryption/main.dart:136:20)
E/flutter (23630): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (23630):
```

my code for downloading file is:

```
_downloadAndCreate(dio,Url, String d, String filename) async {
  if(await canLaunch(Url)){
    print("Data downloding....");
    var resp = await dio.get(Url, options: Options(
        responseType: ResponseType.bytes,
        followRedirects: false,
        validateStatus: (status) { return status < 500; }
    ));
    var encResult= _encryptData(resp);
    String p =await _writeData(encResult,d+'/$filename.aes');
    print("file encrypted successfully: $p");
  }else{
    print("can't launch url.");
  }
}
```

my code for encrypting file is:

```
_encryptData(plainString) {
  print("Encrypting file...");
  final encrypted=
      MyEncrypt.myEncrypter.encryptBytes(plainString,iv: MyEncrypt.myIv);
  return encrypted;
}
```

this is MyEncrypt class:

```
class MyEncrypt {
  static final myKey = enc.Key.fromUtf8('encryptwith2210yogender2209sandipta2330sourav2227deepanshu');
  static final myIv= enc.IV.fromUtf8('Yogendersingh2210');
  static final myEncrypter = enc.Encrypter(enc.AES(myKey));
}
```

please help

Answer (score 0):

sorry for this late response, You need to change

```
var encResult= _encryptData(resp);
```

to

```
var encResult= _encryptData(resp.data);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).